# Which of the following verbs are the most common regarding to meetings?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, frequency

Which of the following verbs are the most common when talking about meetings?

> **Scenario 1**: I should say to my friends that we should _______ meeting after a long time that we didn't see each other.
>
> **Scenario 2**: I should say to my business colleagues that we should to ___?____ about new products that we can market.

There are the options for the verbs that I found here on ELL site, but I want to use the common once and not be sound weird or awkward (especially in the UK or Canada)

> To **do** a meeting.
>
> To **make** a meeting.
>
> To **conduct** a meeting.
>
> To **have** a meeting.
>
> To **hold** a meeting.
>
> To **arrange** a meeting.
>
> To **set up** a meeting.
>
> To **manage** a meeting.
>
> To **determinate** a meeting.

Answer (score 3):

The word "a meeting" is itself too formal to use with friends.  Instead you *meet*, *hook up*, *get together*, *hang out*, etc.

> It's been too long since we **got together**! When are you free to **hook up**?

With professional colleagues, "meeting" is fine.  Any of these verbs work:

> when creating the meeting: *plan, arrange, set up, put together, schedule, organize, book, host, hold, have, convene, call,* etc.
>
> when participating in the meeting: *attend, join, sit in on, be part of,* etc.
>
> when managing a meeting:  *run, host, manage, lead, coordinate, be in charge of,* etc.

Example:

> Let's **schedule** a meeting to discuss the new marketing plan.  I'll **set up** the conference call for those who can't **attend** in person, but you should **run** it since you're more familiar with the subject matter.
>
> There's a meeting about the new marketing plan **going on** in the large conference room.  Do you plan to **sit in**?  The VP **called** the meeting so it must be pretty important.

Comment: Thank you. You said that it's too formal to use 'meeting' with friends. But you suggested things like 'hang out' which in my case not really works if we just meet in a cofee shop without any walking together. Isn't it?

Comment: @COX1  "Hang out" is a colloquialism, so it's very informal, but it actually does not imply any specific activity.  You can "hang out" and just talk, or watch TV, or play a video game, or even hang out while exercising together.  In some cases, a couple can say they "hang out" to mean they are *not* trying to be romantically involved.

Comment: @COX1  which is to say you can "hang out" anywhere -- at the beach, in a coffee shop, at the park, etc.  My brother likes to *hang out* with his friends at the baseball park.

Comment: Based on the definition in the dictionary (Cambridge) it seems to me difficult to call it "hang out" while we are going to meet for half hour or something like that. Is it considered a lot of time? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hang-out

Comment: "**gather**" is also often used informally in the US. Especially if it's going to be a party.

Comment: @COX1  try the [Urban Dictionary definitions](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hang%20out) for a different perspective. *"When people chill and do things together"*.  Although you are correct that you really wouldn't "hang out" for five minutes, half an hour would be fine.

Comment: @SovereignSun  I personally wouldn't say "**gather** up some friends for a party".  I'd use "get together" instead.  But it may be different elsewhere in the US.

Comment: @Andrew I definitily remember hearing, "**I want to gather all my friends for the party.**"